# Graphs vs matrices (when $0$ weight edges are allowed)

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms, network

---

*In short: weighted graphs are equivalent to matrices, where a $0$ entry means that an edge is absent; what if $0$ weights for existing edges is allowed?*

---

It is often claimed, including by myself for the last 20 years, that **matrices are equivalent to weighted graphs**: any $n\times n$ matrix is equivalent to the graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and $E = \{(i,j), M_{i,j}\ne 0\}$, with weights $\omega(i,j) = M_{i,j}$.

This is based on the (generally implicit) assumption that **a $0$ weight is equivalent to a non-edge**, *i.e.* there cannot be any $0$ weight edge.

Then, one may translate many graphs concepts and problems into equivalent matrix concepts and problems, and conversely.

However, one may very well **consider graphs where some *existing* edges have $0$ weight**. In this case, weighted graphs are no longer strictly equivalent to matrices, and I am concerned by the implications of this fact.

In particular, **are there graphs concepts that have no matrix equivalent when $0$ weighted edges are allowed?**

Of course, one may use a special value other than $0$ for non-edges in the matrix, but what consequences would this have on matrix operations? I fear some would not make graph sense anymore.

**Example:**

Consider a graph of friendship relations between individuals, weighted by the number of times they met in a month, say. Certainly, having not met a friend for a month does not mean you are not friends anymore. For any pair of friends $(u,v)$, one may study the number of friends $|N(v)\cap N(u)|$ they have in common, as a function of the number of times they met $\omega(u,v)$. Certainly, the friends that did not met each other still have a higher probability to have friends in common than two random non-connected individuals.

Comment: I have don't have a definitive answer to your question but as you suggest putting a special value is often a sufficient solution. The precise nature of this value will depend on the problem you want to modelize: if you're dealing with shortest path, $+\infty$ will do, but for probabilistic applications $0$ is the same as having no edge.  A nice survey is http://www.numdam.org/item/RO_1975__9_1_77_0/ (I'm assuming you read french). Hope it answers your question.